# Java for tablets on Windows 8

Tags: java, windows, tablet

I need to write a Java application for a Windows 8 tablet where the user will interact mostly by the touch screen.

I have previously used Swing for all my Java application UIs, however Swing looks pretty ugly and probably wouldn't be very good for a touch screen. Are there any good Java libraries out there for designing nice mobile interfaces?

Comment: I have 2 words for you `Java FX`!